# Can cygwin ls show ACLs without providing the DOS path to file?

Tags: cygwin, acl, ls, cygpath

The commands

```
    cd c:/p4
    ls -ld  .  c:/p4  /cygdrive/c/p4
```

shows

```
    d---------+ 1 jgunter Domain Users 0 Apr 27 18:41 .
    d---------+ 1 jgunter Domain Users ? 0 Apr 27 18:41 /cygdrive/c/p4
    drwxr-xr-x  1 jgunter Domain Users ? 0 Apr 27 18:41 c:/p4
```

ls shows the perms I want to see only for files specified with a C:/ path.

I know about getfacl, but I'm hoping there's some ls option that will show me what I want without requiring I spell out absolute paths.

I can do something like:

```
     ls -ld `cygpath -da $@`
```

but when I'm in a deeply nested folder, the output is cluttered by full pathnames.

Comment: I'm confused. You say you want to see ACLs, but then you say you want to see what `ls -ld c:/p4` shows, which is a POSIX permission mask without ACLs (no `+` sign).

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't understand that I was looking at the POSIX permission mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOS path makes cygwin treat the file system as not having ACLs. It means that `ls` shows the correct ACLs, but the same directory is mounted with different options. Therefore `ls` doesn't have such an option, you need a workaround.

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ov-new1.7.html states at 1.7.2:

> Handle native DOS paths always as if mounted with "posix=0,noacl"

Beside this, I think, that `d---------+` is strange. I've tried it on my PC, with 1.7.31 cygwin version, and it shows `drwx------+`, which is a bit better. I had experienced other bugs and strange behaviour in cygwin ACL handling. I guess there is confusion and some hacks about this. `chmod 777` was a good workaround in my case.

Comment: Thanks.  It was the d---------+ perm that was confusing me.  Thanks also for the tip on noacl mounts.